# PDE in clairaut's form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> A solution of the PDE
>
> $$x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2-u=0 $$
>
> represents
>
> (a) an ellipse in the $XY$ plane
>
> (b) an ellipsoid in the $XYU$ space
>
> (c) a parabola in the $UX$ plane
>
> (d) a hyperbola in the $UY$ plane

I know that it is in the $clairaut's$ form, so a solution should be of the form $u=ax+by+a^2+b^2$, $a, b$ are constants. But I am confused how this solution can satisfy any one of them.

Comment: That would be "none of the above".  But there are also solutions of the form $u = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2$ for suitable $a,b,c$.

Comment: Prof. Israel, for  $ u= ax^2+ bxy+ cy^2$  could we tick option a and c with sutiable $a,b,c$ ? thanks prof.

Comment: The solution is not an ellipse in the xy plane, though its level curves can be.